# How to play rosbag file from node

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Long story short, I am trying to play a bag file from a node and mimic the same functionality of the following:

```
rosbag play -l recorded1.bag
```

Before I dive in to the rosbag API, I thought I'd ask the question if there was a simpler way than using the API, which I am not completely familiar with.

If the API was the way, I was thinking something like this:

```
import rosbag
bag = rosbag.Bag('test.bag')
% Loop
    for topic, msg, t in bag.read_messages(topics=['chatter', 'numbers']):
        %Publish Messages
```

Am I on the right track?

Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/144646/how-to-play-rosbag-file-from-node/) by [TFinleyosu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4405/tfinleyosu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 385 on 2014-03-26

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-03-26**:
curiosity: Why would you want to implement that yourself? You can start rosbag like this also as node via launch file...

**Comment by [TFinleyosu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4405/tfinleyosu/) on 2014-03-26**:
I am doing a research study and I need to be able to play a random bag file of Kinect data when a button is pressed in another node. The button will be used many times and I need to avoid any terminal commands.

Am I able to launch a launch file from within a node?

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-03-26**:
Yes the rosbag API seems to be the straight forward solution in this case I think. YOU could call into the rosbag via system command, but you would have to open the rosbag after every button press, so I think the application would be very slow and unresponsive...

**Comment by [TFinleyosu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4405/tfinleyosu/) on 2014-03-27**:
Thanks for the help Wolf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rosbag play application itself is implemented in C++:
[play.cpp](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/indigo-devel/tools/rosbag/src/play.cpp)

The code relevant to publishing messages can be found in the method Player::publish(). The C++ file also contains code for pausing and resuming playback, console output etc., but maybe you can use this code to get a rough idea:
[player.cpp](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/indigo-devel/tools/rosbag/src/player.cpp)

I'd expect Python to give slightly worse performance compared to C++ if you plan to play large bagfiles (e.g. containing camera images).

---

Edit, to answer your question: I believe there is no other way than either

- using the C++ API (should provide best performance)
- using the Python API
- invoking "rosbag play" using a system() command.

---

Originally posted by [timm](https://answers.ros.org/users/6556/timm/) with karma: 376 on 2014-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TFinleyosu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4405/tfinleyosu/) on 2014-03-27**:
Great point. Thanks for the guidance. I will get to this soon and post my solution for reference.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here was my solution for future  reference. Please feel free to critique it.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <rosbag/bag.h>
#include <rosbag/view.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Image.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <ros/package.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "publish_scene");

    ros::NodeHandle n;

    ros::Publisher d_info_pub = n.advertise<sensor_msgs::CameraInfo>("scene/depth/camera_info", 1);
    ros::Publisher d_points_pub = n.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>("scene/depth/points", 1);
    ros::Publisher rgb_info_pub = n.advertise<sensor_msgs::CameraInfo>("scene/rgb/camera_info", 1);
    ros::Publisher rgb_image_pub = n.advertise<sensor_msgs::Image>("scene/rgb/image", 1);
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

  std::string package_path = ros::package::getPath("pick");
  std::string scene_path;

  while (ros::ok()){

    int scene_number;
    if (n.getParam("/scene/number", scene_number))
    {
      ROS_INFO("Scene Number: %i \n",scene_number);
      std::stringstream sstm;
      if (scene_number > 9)
        sstm << package_path << "/scenes/scene_" << scene_number << ".bag";
      else
        sstm << package_path << "/scenes/scene_0" << scene_number << ".bag";
      
      scene_path = sstm.str();
    }
    else
    {
      ROS_INFO("rosparam /scene/number not set");
      break;
    }

    rosbag::Bag bag;
    bag.open(scene_path, rosbag::bagmode::Read);

    std::string depth_cam_info = "/camera/depth_registered/camera_info";
    std::string depth_points = "/camera/depth_registered/points";
    std::string rgb_cam_info = "/camera/rgb/camera_info";
    std::string rgb_cam_image = "/camera/rgb/image_color";

    std::vector<std::string> topics;
    topics.push_back(depth_cam_info);
    topics.push_back(depth_points);
    topics.push_back(rgb_cam_info);
    topics.push_back(rgb_cam_image);

    rosbag::View view(bag, rosbag::TopicQuery(topics));

    BOOST_FOREACH(rosbag::MessageInstance const m, view)
    {
      if (m.getTopic() == depth_cam_info) 
      {
        sensor_msgs::CameraInfo::ConstPtr d_info_ptr = m.instantiate<sensor_msgs::CameraInfo>();
        if (d_info_ptr != NULL)
          d_info_pub.publish(*d_info_ptr);
      }
        
      if (m.getTopic() == depth_points) 
      {
        sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::ConstPtr d_points_ptr = m.instantiate<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>();
        if (d_points_ptr != NULL)
          d_points_pub.publish(*d_points_ptr);
      }
        
      if (m.getTopic() == rgb_cam_info) 
      {
        sensor_msgs::CameraInfo::ConstPtr rgb_info_ptr = m.instantiate<sensor_msgs::CameraInfo>();
        if (rgb_info_ptr != NULL)
          rgb_info_pub.publish(*rgb_info_ptr);
      }
      
      if (m.getTopic() == rgb_cam_image) 
      {
        sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr rgb_image_ptr = m.instantiate<sensor_msgs::Image>();
        if (rgb_image_ptr != NULL)
          rgb_image_pub.publish(*rgb_image_ptr);
      }

    }

  bag.close();
  ros::spinOnce();
  loop_rate.sleep();

  }

}
```

---

Originally posted by [TFinleyosu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4405/tfinleyosu/) with karma: 385 on 2014-03-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [emacsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/3662/emacsd/) on 2015-02-27**:
Thanks for sharing :)

**Comment by [Will Chamberlain](https://answers.ros.org/users/21723/will-chamberlain/) on 2016-08-30**:
In addition to excellent answer above, the [rosbag API page](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API) links to some [cookbook code snippets](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook).

**Comment by [hannavaj](https://answers.ros.org/users/38980/hannavaj/) on 2018-12-12**:
Hey does the above code preserve the desired output frequency on various topics?? Say our bag has 2 topics and if there are more messages in one topic than the other one. Does this approach publish data on these two topics at different( but appropriate) frequency rates ?

**Comment by [Wade](https://answers.ros.org/users/122619/wade/) on 2022-11-02**:
Hello, could anyone suggest how can we add play rate of the rosbag in the above code as posted by @TFinleyosu ??